# Trying to fetch the discount and tax amount item-wise: Magento 2

Tags: checkout, cart, magento2.2

I am facing issue when we add configurable product of virtual item. The price, tax and discount shows in parent item only.

How can I fetch that for child?

```
foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $itemv) 
{
    $itemid = $itemv->getProductId();
    $DiscountRate = $itemv->getDiscountAmount();
    $UnitTax = $itemv->getTaxAmount();
    $price = $product_data->getPrice();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**getAllVisibleItems** Only give u give parent item details.

If you want to  ***get child items of an item then you can use***

`$itemv->getChildrenItems()`,it is give ***an array of child item of that item***